# Solving Nonlinear Shallow Water Equations using Predictor-Corrector Adam Bashforth Moulton

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, partial-derivative

I want to solve nonlinear homogeneous shallow water equation using Adam Bashforth as Predictor and Adam Moulton as corrector. For the second and third step I used lax-Friedrich method.

The Shallow water equation I want to solve is :

\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial t}} = E\left( {\eta ,u} \right)\\
\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = F\left( {\eta ,u} \right)\\
E =  - \frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}\left[ {\left( {h + \eta } \right)u} \right];F =  - g\frac{{\partial \eta }}{{\partial t}} - u\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial x}}
\end{array}

For calculating the first derivative respect to x, I used center difference with fourth order accuracy.

I've tried to make the matlab code for the method, but I found that if I make the time longer, the result become unstable.

Here is my matlab code :

```
    % Predictor- Corrector Method 
% for solving Non Linear Shallow Water Equation
% NSWE to solve:
% h_t = E (h,u)
% u_t  = F(h,u)
% Notes:
% E = -(Hu)_x
% F = -g*u_x - u*u_x
% h = free surface elevation
% u = horizontal velocity
% d = local water depth
% H = total depth of water ( H = h + d )  
% g = gravitational acceleration

% simulation for flat bottom (constant local water depth 'd')
% using zero order extrapolation boundary condition

% Predictor : 3rd Order Adam-Bashforth
% Corrector : 4th Order Adam-Moulton
% Lax-Friedrics scheme is used before using Adams Bashforth Moulton


function PrediktorKorektor
clc;
clear all;
close all;

Ix = [-40 100];                          % boundary of x(space)
It = [0 5];                              % boundary of t (time)
dx = 0.125;                              % space steps
dt = 0.012;                              % time steps
x = Ix(1):dx:Ix(2);                      % grid x
t = It(1):dt:It(2);                      % grid t
Nx = length(x);                          % calculate the number of grid x
Nt = length(t);                          % calculate the number of grid t
u = zeros(Nx,Nt);                        % matrix solution of u
h = zeros (Nx,Nt);                       % matrix solution of h
E = zeros(Nx,Nt);
F = zeros(Nx,Nt);

nu = dt/(2*dx);



% ----- calculate first derivative respect to x

% center difference
f1=@(y1,y2,y3,y4) ((8*(y3-y2))-(y4-y1))/(12*dx);


%---- calculate E dan F

function y = calcE(j,n)
    % center difference
    a = f1(u(j-2,n),u(j-1,n),u(j+1,n),u(j+2,n));
    b = f1(h(j-2,n)*u(j-2,n),h(j-1,n)*u(j-1,n),h(j+1,n)*u(j+1,n),h(j+2,n)*u(j+2,n));
    y = -d*a-b;
end

function z = calcF(j,n)
    % ---center difference
    z=-g*f1(h(j-2,n),h(j-1,n),h(j+1,n),h(j+2,n))-...
      (u(j,n)*f1(u(j-2,n),u(j-1,n),u(j+1,n),u(j+2,n)));
end




% ---------- Main Program ---------

% boundary condition and initial value
u(1,:)= 0;
u(Nx,:)= 0;
A = 0.5;
w=4;
d = 1;                  % local water depth
g=9.8;
y = x-20;
h(:,1)=A*exp(-2.*y.^2/w^2);
for j=3:Nx-2
    E(j,1)=calcE(j,1);
    F(j,1)=calcF(j,1);
end


figure
plot(x,h(:,1),'b'),hold on 
grid on;


k=1;

for n=2:Nt

    % Lax-Friedrich Scheme
    if n<=3
        for j=3:(Nx-2)
            h(j,n)=0.5*(h(j-1,n-1)+h(j+1,n-1))-d*nu*(u(j+1,n-1)-u(j-1,n-1))-...
                d*nu*(h(j+1,n-1)*u(j+1,n-1)-h(j-1,n-1)*u(j-1,n-1));
            u(j,n)=0.5*(u(j-1,n-1)+u(j+1,n-1))-g*nu*(h(j+1,n-1)-h(j-1,n-1))-...
                (u(j,n-1)*nu*(u(j+1,n-1))-u(j-1,n-1));
        end

        % calculate E(j,n) dan F (j,n)
        for j=3:(Nx-2)
            E(j,n)=calcE(j,n);
            F(j,n)=calcF(j,n);
        end

    end

    % predictor - corrector scheme 
    if n>3
        for j=3:(Nx-2)
            % predictor
            h(j,n) = h(j,n-1)+(dt/12)*(23*E(j,n-1)-16*E(j,n-2)+5*E(j,n-3));
            u(j,n) = u(j,n-1)+(dt/12)*(23*F(j,n-1)-16*F(j,n-2)+5*F(j,n-3));
        end
        h(1,n)=h(3,n);
        h(2,n)=h(3,n);
        h(end,n)=h(end-2,n);
        h(end-1,n)=h(end-2,n);

        % calculate E* dan F*
        for j=3:(Nx-2)
            % center difference
            E(j,n)=calcE(j,n);
            F(j,n)=calcF(j,n);
        end

       err1 = 1;
       err2 = 1; 
       while err1 > 0.001 || err2 > 0.001
            % --- save approximating value previous iteration
            h1=h(:,n);
            u1=u(:,n);

            % --- Corrector
            for j=3:(Nx-2)
                h(j,n)=h(j,n-1)+((dt/24)*(9*E(j,n)+19*E(j,n-1)-5*E(j,n-2)+E(j,n-3)));
                u(j,n)=u(j,n-1)+((dt/24)*(9*F(j,n)+19*F(j,n-1)-5*F(j,n-2)+F(j,n-3)));
            end

            for j=3:(Nx-2)
                E(j,n)=calcE(j,n);
                F(j,n)=calcF(j,n);
            end

            err1 = sum(abs(h(3:end-2,n)-h1(3:end-2)))/sum(abs(h(3:end-2,n)));
            err2 = sum(abs(u(3:end-2,n)-u1(3:end-2)))/sum(abs(u(3:end-2,n)));
       end
    end

    h(1,n)=h(3,n);
    h(2,n)=h(3,n);
    h(end,n)=h(end-2,n);
    h(end-1,n)=h(end-2,n);

    if or(n==1,mod(n,20)==0)
        k=k+1;
        plot(x,h(:,n)+0.2*k,'b'),hold on
        drawnow
        grid on;
    end
end


figure(2)
plot(x,h(:,80),'r-o',x,h(:,400),'b-*'), hold on
grid on;

figure(3)
surf(x,t,h');
shading flat
zlim([0 3]);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('t');
zlabel('eta');

end
```

and here is the result I get:

[image: the last six results are unstable]

[image: I plot the graph at 80th and 400th iteration]

I hadn't found where I miss in the code. Thanks in advanced

Comment: What, exactly, is it about your graphs that you find worrying? What do they show? You have not included labels.

Comment: @Lovsovs ahh sorry, I forgot to label the graph, the horizontal axis is x, and the vertical axis is surface elevation. Yess, you can see in the graph, as the time increase, the resulted value of surface elevation is not stable (they are up and down)

Answer (score 2):

You are observing severe oscillations because the methods you use are not suitable for simulating this type of problem (hyperbolic conservation laws).

It is well known that the second order accurate, central finite difference
$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x -h)}{2 h}$$ is unconditionally unstable. It looks like something similar holds also for the fourth order method you are using (although the oscillations could be induced by the temporal integrator). A first remedy to this problem are [upwind-like methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme) that you could try. The typical property you want your scheme to posess is that the [Total Variation diminishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_diminishing). Roughly speaking, it ensures that oscillations like in your case cannot increase from one timestep to the next.

Next, your time integrator should also be [stability-preserving](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S003614450036757X), which is [likely to not be the case](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304439.pdf) for the standard Adams-Bashforth methods. However, [explicit Euler is TVD, see Chapter 5.8](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2013/math/nhdgl/numcl_notes_HOMEPAGE.pdf) and might a first choice to implement.

As a final remark: Problems like yours are usually solved with [Finite Volume Schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method), rather than finite-difference based methods which assume sufficient smoothness/differentiability/regularity of your solution, which is simply not the case for actual physics. Thus, even methods (like explicit Euler) which are on their own TVD, may break down for a point-based finite difference treatment rather than a cell/averaged based finite-volume method.